# Transform any ActionScript class in XML

Tags: java, xml, apache-flex, xml-serialization, xml-deserialization

For a program i'm writing I need to marshal ActionScript classes to a format that is later to be read by Java (and back again).
What solutions exists for such a need ?

Is there a way (like when using Java through XMLEncoder/XMLDecoder) to generate that XML using standard flex libraries (that would be compatible with later decoding using XMLDecoder) ?
Or is there a good existing library ?

**EDIT** Yes, this question is a duplicate of [Are there any tool mapping of JavaBeans to ActionScript Class through xml serialization and deserialization?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4755775/are-there-any-tool-mapping-of-javabeans-to-actionscript-class-through-xml-seriali), but I will accept correct answers and eventually start a bounty if no answer satisfies my needs. (in other words, i plan to make the previous - unanswered - question a duplicate of mine).

**EDIT 2** To be even more precise, I have an application divided in two parts : one Flex GUI and one Java core. They communicate over a **[non http](http://cssdk.host.adobe.com/sdk/1.0/docs/WebHelp/About.htm)** layer which requires data to be sent in [XML](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/XML.html). In this context, I replicated my Java objects in Flex (using [GAS3](http://www.graniteds.org/confluence/display/DOC/3.+Gas3+Code+Generator)) and now want some of these objects to be sent from Flex to Java and back again.
For that purpose, I have to serialize objects (on the Flex end) in XML and deserialize them in Java (and all that back again).

Comment: Why not write your own code for the class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution used was to put [XStream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/) on the java side and [FleXMLer](http://code.google.com/p/flexmler/) (with some adaptations that can be found there : https://github.com/Riduidel/FleXMLer) on the Flex side. it works quite good (once FleXMLer is adapted to XStream architecture).

Answer (score 1):

We are using http://www.spicefactory.org/parsley/index.php which supports XML-to-object conversions back-and-forth. Their documentation is very decent: http://www.spicefactory.org/parsley/docs/2.4/manual/.

Answer (score 0):

See [describeType](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/package.html#describeType%28%29) function if you really want XML. But I seriously recommend considering the other serializations formats too.

You can look into JSON. The classes needed for the actionscript serialization/deserialization are part of the [as3corelib](https://github.com/mikechambers/as3corelib) library.

You might also want to take a look at [BlazeDS](http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/blazeds/Overview).

Comment: My communication *requires* XML interexchange format, and does not uses any kind of HTTP communication, which makes BlazeDS, GraniteDS and others *DS non-answsers.